# Can't connect to my AD LDAP Server

Tags: active-directory, ldap, authentication

I just installed an AD on a VM running Windows Server 2016.

I want to connect to the LDAP server using a explorer like JXplorer or Apache Directory Server, because I will develop a Java application that will use that LDAP as authentication server.

So, I've created a standard AD, [with some users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2BBv.png)

But, when I go to JXplorer, I always get the same error:

```
Error opening connection:
[LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903D3, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v3839
```

I'm a little new to LDAP and AD, so don't know what's wrong.

I see through AD Administrative Center that user "juan" is in CN=Users,DC=i3test,DC=es but can't connect with that string
[JXplorer connection screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOtCi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data 52e is the key, this means that the AD server is saying 'Invalid Credentials.'. I'm not readily familiar with JXplorer so I'm not sure how you set the credential for the session, but something is going awry there.

Comment: I was typing the password wrong